# What does this PL-SQL statement mean?

Tags: sql, plsql

```
:a:b    :=c
```

- a,b are of sb4 type.
- c is of type number inside PL-SQL block.

I need to make sense of this line to move further. I haven't had a formal learning of PL-SQL, so how can I make sense of this statement?

Is it assigning the value of c to both a and b? Or it is something else?

Comment: If you provide a couple of lines preceding and following the above then it would be easier to answer. By now your snippet seems to be syntactically meaningless.

Comment: It is something, a typo in your code or an accidental find and  replace!

Comment: Have a read about [host variables] (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_04dat.htm#i27299) and [indicator variables] (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_04dat.htm#i12463). Hope this answers your question